# How to use aggregate with condition in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have a dataframe.
Following code works

```
stat = working_data.groupby(by=['url', 'bucket_id'], 
                            as_index=False).agg({'delta': 'max','id': 'count'})
```

Now i need to count ids with different statuses. I have "DOWNLOADED", "NOT_DOWNLOADED" and "DOWNLOADING" for the status.

I would like to have `df` with columns `bucket_id`, `max`, `downloaded` (how many have "DOWNLOADED" status) , `not_downloaded` (how many have "NOT_DOWNLOADED" status) , `downloading` (how many have "DOWNLOADING" status). How to make it?

Input I have:
 [image].

Output i have:
 [image]

As you can see count isn't devided by status. But i want to know that there are x downloaded, y not_downloaded, z downloading for each bucket_id  bucket_id (so they should be in separate columns, but info for one bucket_id should be in one row)

Comment: Add statuses to ```by``` in your ```groupby```. Then use ```pandas.pivot_table()```. It's hard to tell more, unless you provide sample of your data and expected output in a more clear format

Comment: What column is the Downloaded and Not_downloaded status in?

Comment: @MBACoder column called status. Next structure of df i have: id | bucket_id| status | delta

Comment: @GrzegorzSkibinski i edited the question a bit, added screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to use assign to create columns then aggregate this new column.

```
working_data.assign(downloaded=df['status'] == 'DOWNLOADED', 
                   not_downloaded=df['status'] == 'NOT_DOWNLOADED',
                   downloading=df['status'] == 'DOWNLOADING')\
            .groupby(by=['url', 'bucket_id'], 
                        as_index=False).agg({'delta': 'max',
                                             'id': 'count',
                                             'downloaded': 'sum',
                                             'not_donwloaded':'sum',
                                             'downloading':'sum'})
```